# How to Merge/Combine 2 select statemenst based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following 2 select statements which I would like to merge having the entry and exit times next to each other in table based on the Date column which must match.

```
     SELECT NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER, CONVERT(VARCHAR,(MIN(TRANSIT_DATE)),114) AS [ENTRY],'' AS      [EXIT], CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103)AS [DATE] 
  FROM [10.230.0.15].[SCAT].[dbo].[HA_TRANSIT] a
  WHERE STR_DIRECTION = 'Entry'
  and a.IDENTIFIER = '20045619'
  AND STR_TRANSIT_STATUS = 'Granted'
  AND TRANSIT_DATE BETWEEN @CompleteSDate AND @CompleteEDate
  GROUP BY NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103) 


 SELECT NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER, '' AS [ENTRY],CONVERT(VARCHAR,(MAX(TRANSIT_DATE)),114) AS [EXIT], CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103)AS [DATE] 
 FROM [10.230.0.15].[SCAT].[dbo].[HA_TRANSIT] a
 WHERE STR_DIRECTION = 'Exit'
 and a.IDENTIFIER = '20045619'
 AND STR_TRANSIT_STATUS = 'Granted'
 AND TRANSIT_DATE BETWEEN @CompleteSDate AND @CompleteEDate
 GROUP BY NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103)
```

> RESULTS of Query 1 NAME   SURNAME IDENTIFIER  ENTRY    EXIT   DATE
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619          07:11:01:000      10/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619          06:58:58:000      11/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619          07:04:27:000      12/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619          07:02:48:000      13/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619          07:17:43:000      16/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619          06:54:35:000      17/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619        07:00:36:000        18/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619          06:57:33:000      19/09/2013
>
> RESULTS of Query 2 NAME   SURNAME IDENTIFIER     ENTRY    EXIT
>   DATE ANTONETTE    COLEMAN 20045619        16:09:39:000    10/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619        16:01:19:000    11/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619        16:18:49:000    12/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619        16:04:28:000    13/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619        16:06:04:000    16/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619        16:05:30:000    17/09/2013
>   ANTONETTE COLEMAN 20045619        16:02:00:000    18/09/2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need two SELECTs, the only difference in your WHERE-conditions is STR_DIRECTION. Just move it into CASEs:

```
   SELECT NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,(MIN(CASE WHEN STR_DIRECTION = 'Entry' THEN TRANSIT_DATE END)),114) AS [ENTRY],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR,(MAX(CASE WHEN STR_DIRECTION = 'Exit'  THEN TRANSIT_DATE END)),114) AS [EXIT],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103)AS [DATE] 
   FROM [10.230.0.15].[SCAT].[dbo].[HA_TRANSIT] a
   WHERE STR_DIRECTION IN ('Entry', 'Exit')
   AND a.IDENTIFIER = '20045619'
   AND STR_TRANSIT_STATUS = 'Granted'
   AND TRANSIT_DATE BETWEEN @CompleteSDate AND @CompleteEDate
   GROUP BY NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103)
```

Comment: This looks like what im looking for but its complaining about a Incorrect syntax near ')' Can't seem to be a bracket as they are all tying up...

Comment: I just forgot the ENDs in my CASEs. FIxed my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER, CONVERT(VARCHAR,(MIN(TRANSIT_DATE)),114) AS [ENTRY],''     AS      [EXIT], CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103)AS [DATE] 
  FROM [10.230.0.15].[SCAT].[dbo].[HA_TRANSIT] a
  WHERE STR_DIRECTION = 'Entry'
 and a.IDENTIFIER = '20045619'
 AND STR_TRANSIT_STATUS = 'Granted'
 AND TRANSIT_DATE BETWEEN @CompleteSDate AND @CompleteEDate
 GROUP BY NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103) 

UNION

 SELECT NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER, '' AS [ENTRY],CONVERT(VARCHAR,    (MAX(TRANSIT_DATE)),114) AS [EXIT], CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103)AS [DATE] 
FROM [10.230.0.15].[SCAT].[dbo].[HA_TRANSIT] a
WHERE STR_DIRECTION = 'Exit'
and a.IDENTIFIER = '20045619'
AND STR_TRANSIT_STATUS = 'Granted'
AND TRANSIT_DATE BETWEEN @CompleteSDate AND @CompleteEDate
GROUP BY NAME, SURNAME,IDENTIFIER,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRANSIT_DATE,103)
```

Comment: YOU used Union to merge or combine two or more than two select statements

Comment: No you can't just do a union, as the exit and entry dates must be next to each other in 1 row if the dates are the same